# Video Recording to Network/Server

Tags: macos, video, server

We've got a lecture series that runs regularly and they usually only want 10-15 minutes recorded a week. I'm looking for a solution where I can install a go-pro or some other camera in the classroom and control it remotely on my mac. Be nice to if I could somehow have that video saved to our server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which GoPro you get. The newer ones can wirelessly transfer to an iOs device (you have osx tagged so I assume this is what you want to do) and since you want to control it remotely on a mac anyway, it'll be easy to edit and upload to your server from there.